# Get rows corresponding to the same time ranges

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have two timestamps forming a range like

```sql
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 01:00:00 UTC') AND TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 02:00:00 UTC')
```

I want to get all rows that fall into these time ranges by some timestamp column. The [`TIME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions) function in BigQuery helps achieve this but using this function falls short when the timestamp range crosses the `00:00:00` clock. That is:

```sql
TIME(ts_col) 
BETWEEN TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 01:00:00 UTC'))
AND TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 02:00:00 UTC'))
```

works, but the following will not:

```sql
TIME(ts_col) 
BETWEEN TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-07 23:00:00 UTC'))
AND TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 01:00:00 UTC'))
```

e.g.

```sql
SELECT 
    TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 00:00:00 UTC')) 
    BETWEEN TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-07 23:00:00 UTC'))
    AND TIME(TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 01:00:00 UTC'))
```

returns `false`. Any ideas? I can guarantee that this range does not exceed 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The `TIME` function will extract only the time part (eg. hour, minute, second) from a timestamp. So when used in your example, the range in `BETWEEN` is invalid because the first time (23:00:00) is greater then the second (01:00:00).

Removing the `TIME` function will work has expected:

```sql
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 00:00:00 UTC')
    BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2022-12-07 23:00:00 UTC')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2022-12-08 01:00:00 UTC')
```

Output:

[image]

More info: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#time

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for though. I'm looking for ALL rows that fall under a time range, so for the example linked, I'm looking for rows that fits between `2022-12-7 23` to `2022-12-08 01` + `2022-12-6 23` to `2022-12-07 01`, `2022-12-5 23` to `2022-12-06 01`... etc

Comment: @bli00 What about put multiple conditions, like: `WHERE col BETWEEN t1 AND t2 OR col BETWEEN t3 AND t4 ...` and so on.

Comment: That would work as a hard coded solution but not if the number of days is unknown